# webkit Center equivalent for IE and edge

Tags: css, button, text-align

Is it correct to use `display: block` to center buttons on IE or should I look for a way using WebKit-center for other browsers?

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .flex {
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .flex_height {
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .grid_8 {
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        width:98%;
        margin-left:1%;
        margin-right:1%;
        text-align:-webkit-center;
        text-align:-moz-center;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_8">
    <button type="button" class="button_home mobile_on">
    *php code to generate text for a button here*
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not `text-align: center;`?

Comment: Tried that, the buttons don't move

Comment: Your css is not related to html

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @TylerH how do I make this better? slightly confused by what i should include

Comment: @dovefromhell Well, I was partially reiterating what Morpheus said, and partially linking you to the Stack Overflow standard for 'good examples. The post editor includes a "Code Snippet" feature that lets you put runnable HTML, CSS, and JS in a post. I'll edit to show you, now that you've provided an update to your HTML.

Comment: @dovefromhell the MCVE I linked above means 'your example needs to be a *complete* demo; it needs to be enough code to reproduce your issue. If we take your code and try to run it, and can't reproduce it, then it's not an MCVE, basically.

Comment: And now, with `text-align: center;` applied per @LarsBeck comment, your button *does* center in IE, using the code you've provided: https://jsfiddle.net/yyeqpbe8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `inline-block` will wrap to the width of its content, so there's no point on *centering* a button inside an `inline-block`.

See:

```css
.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-block">
  <button>Button Label</button>
</div>
<p><em>As you can see, the button is already centered inside the red inline-block.</em></p>
```

Instead, you could use a regular block (not inline) element with `text-align: center` to center the button.

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Button Label</button>
</div>
```

Or, if you really need this `inline-block` element, then you'll have to wrap it all in an outer wrapper:

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inline-block">
    <button>Button Label</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Besides that, you could also use some *hacks* as relative positioning, negative margins or transforms. But, I'd try to keep it simple.

```css
.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: -41px; /* Magic number. Not recommended! */
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateX(-50%); /* Much better, but still... */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="blue" class="inline-block">
    <button>Button Label</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div id="red" class="inline-block">
    <button>Button Label</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi downvoter, could you please add some suggestion for me to improve my answer? Thank you.